# Product of connected spaces- subset

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{{X_\lambda}\}$ with $\lambda \in  I $ a family of connected spaces. Let fix a $p=(p_\lambda)\in X=\prod X_\lambda$, where $X$ has the product topology.

Everything looks quite normal here, but the next senteces knocked me out, firstly I cannot understand intuitively so I am not able to give a proof, herewe go:

For any $K\subset I$ finite. Let be $X_K=\{(x_\lambda)\in X :x_\lambda=p_\lambda \forall \lambda \notin K\}$. Prove $X_\lambda$ is connected.

Like we have to proof connectedness, we assume otherwise, so if $G$ and $H$ ara a disconnection of $X_k$ in $X$, my problem is that I can not find any contradiction because what I wrote before.....

Comment: $X_K$ is in effect a finite product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_K$ is homeomorphic to $\prod_{\lambda \in K} X_\lambda$ (the projection is open and continuous and is bijective on $X_K$ by construction...) and presumably as a lemma of sorts, you did the fact that a *finite* product of connected spaces is connected, which you can see by a sort of glueing lemma for $2$ spaces, plus induction.